# Using jopendocument with coldfusion/railo, how to add table row?

Tags: coldfusion, railo, opendocument

I'm using jopendocument 1.2 with Railo 3.3.1.000

from http://www.jopendocument.org/start_text_2.html

```
List<Map<String, String>> months = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
months.add(createMap("January", "-12", "3"));
months.add(createMap("February", "-8", "5"));
months.add(createMap("March", "-5", "12"));
months.add(createMap("April", "-1", "15"));
months.add(createMap("May", "3", "21"));
template.setField("months", months);
```

How to write that code in cfml, or anyone have experience with jopendocument to add row in odt template file with cfml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `List<Map<String, String>> months = new ArrayList<Map<String,
>   String>>();`

In CF terms, that code creates an array of structures. Because java is strongly typed the code uses generics to indicate what type of objects each one contains

```
    List< Map<...> >          // Array containing structures 
    Map< String, String >     // Structure containing "String" values
```

Fortunately CF arrays are `java.util.List` objects internally and structures are `java.util.Map` objects. So you only need to create a CF array of structures with the proper keys and values. Then pass the array into `template.setField(...)`.

I was not sure which keys to use in the structure, so I downloaded the "test.odt" template from [jOpenDocument-template-1.2.zip](http://jopendocument.org/download/jOpenDocument-template-1.2.zip). It revealed each structure should contain three (3) keys, one for each column in the table: `name`, `min`, `max`. As long as you populate the structures with *strings*, this should work:

```
// Create an array of structures. Each structure represents a table row. 
// The key names for columns 1-3 are: "name", "min", "max"
months = [
            {name="January", min="-12", max="3"}
            , {name="February", min="-8", max="5"}
            , {name="March", min="-5", max="12"}
            , {name="April", min="-1", max="15"}
            , {name="May", min="3", max="21"}
            , {name="June", min="5", max="32"}
        ];  

// populate table rows
template.setField("months", months);
```